# Untar / Unzip *.tar.xz with ANT

Tags: ant, tar, unzip, gunzip

I want to extract a tarball-file with *.tar.xz with ant.

But I can only find, bunzip2, gunzip, unzip and untar as goals in ant and none of it seems to work.

So how can I expand a tarball-file with *.tar.xz with ant?

Answer (score 4):

The XZ format is not supported by the default Ant distribution, you'll need the [Apache Compress Antlib](https://ant.apache.org/antlibs/compress/index.html).

Download the full Antlib with all the dependencies from [here](https://ant.apache.org/antlibs/bindownload.cgi) (add the three jars `ant-compress`,`common-compress`,`xz` in the `lib` directory of your ant), and use this task:

```
<target name="unxz">
    <cmp:unxz src="foo.tar.xz" xmlns:cmp="antlib:org.apache.ant.compress"/>
    <untar src="foo.tar" dest="."/>
    <delete file="foo.tar"/>
</target>
```

You have to use this two-steps process because even with the additional ant library, the `"xz"` value is still not supported by the `compression` attribute of the `untar` task, the task you'll normally use to extract compressed tars.

Comment: You can use the "nested resource" support of `untar` together with the Compress Antlib's `xzresource` in order to avoid the temporary file

    <untar dest=".">
      <cmp:xzresource>
        <file file="foo.tar.xz"/>
      </cmp:xzresource>
    </untar>

Comment: @StefanBodewig way better!!

Answer (score 3):

In case somebody else like myself wants to do the same with maven managing ant.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <dependencies>
<!--    Optional:   May want to use more up to date commons compress, add this dependency
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-compress</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals><goal>run</goal></goals>
            <configuration>
                <target name="unpack">
                    <taskdef resource="org/apache/ant/compress/antlib.xml" classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath"/>
                    <unxz src="${xz.download.file}" dest="${tar.unpack.directory}" />
                    <untar src="${tar.unpack.file}" dest="${final.unpack.directory}"/>
                </target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```