# How do I use ant-compress within Gradle (untar an xz tar file)?

Tags: gradle, ant

I want to untar a file that is in `.tar.xz` format.  Gradle's `tarTree()` does not support this format, so I need to unzip the `.xz` to a `.tar`, then I can make use of it.

According to the [docs](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html), i should be able to do something like this:

```
    ant.untar(src: myTarFile, compression: "xz", dest: extractDir)
```

However, I get an error:

```
Caused by: : xz is not a legal value for this attribute
    at org.apache.tools.ant.types.EnumeratedAttribute.setValue(EnumeratedAttribute.java:94)
```

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32236361/272023) talks about using the Apache Ant Compress antlib within Maven.  How can I achieve a similar result using Gradle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting the Maven SO answer in your link would be something like:

```
configurations {
   antCompress
} 
dependencies {
   antCompress 'org.apache.ant:ant-compress:1.4'
}
task untar {
   ext {
      xzFile = file('path/to/file.xz')
      outDir = "$buildDir/untar"
   } 
   inputs.file xzFile
   outputs.dir outDir
   doLast {
      ant.taskdef(
          resource:"org/apache/ant/compress/antlib.xml" 
          classpath: configurations.antCompress.asPath
      ) 
      ant.unxz(src:xzFile.absolutePath, dest:"$buildDir/unxz.tar" )
      copy {
         from tarTree("$buildDir/unxz.tar") 
         into outDir
      }   
   } 
}
```

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/ant.html

Comment: Hi, do you know if it's possible to pipe outputs to avoid intermediary files ?, I.e. currently I'm creating intermediary files via `ant.unar(src: debFile.absolutePath, dest: "folder"); ant.unxz(src: "folder/data.tar.xz", dest: "folder/data.tar");`

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution that involves command line utilities.

```
task untar() {
    inputs.property('archiveFile', 'path/to/file.xz')
    inputs.property('dest', 'path/to/file.xz')
    outputs.dir("${buildDir}/destination")
    doLast {
        mkdir("${buildDir}/destination")
        exec {
            commandLine('tar', 'xJf', inputs.properties.archiveFile, '-C', "${buildDir}/destination")
        }
    }
}
```